# Materialized view bigger than table it is based on?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

I have a database that's ~130 GB and one table makes up for most of this (85 GB). Because this table holds a lot of duplicates, we have a materialized view which basically uses a window function to only select the newest rows.

The original table holds 85 mio. records and the materialized view is expected to have approximately 15 mio. records. So I would expect about 15 GB of disk usage. There are no additional attributes in the view, that are not already in the table.

However, when I invoke `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` it fails with "not enough disk space", even though there are 160 GB free. I checked and it really writes that much (and then rolls back).

Why would I need that much space? 160 GB is almost twice of the original table, although it should contain only 1/5 of the data.

I am running Postgresql 10.6.

Comment: Did you check where it is writing that much?  The pg_wal, the temp tablespace, the final location?  What is the EXPLAIN (or better EXPLAIN ANALYZE) for the query the materialized view is based on?

Comment: I did check now. It writes to /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/base/pgsql_tmp. The explain for the query is: https://explain.depesz.com/s/q4Nw

Comment: You are sorting the entire table to disk (temp files) before any filtering is done, so that explains where at least half of the space goes.